# Why updates are not showing on Magento 1.9 front end

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, upgrade

I change in my file and when I see at frontend, no changes are affected.

I am very confused even after flushing Magento cache, updates are not showing on the front end.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: had you check below my answer?

Comment: Do you have cron running?

Comment: @Anil , if my answer is correct for you then you can correct my answer as right answer. Thanks

Comment: Please, update your post and add more informations, what you're trying to update, which file and what you have done ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to do edit in correct file. So for get correct file path follow link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

Comment: I had already checked this so this answer is not helpful .BTW thanks . Keep supporting